# Open URL inside a tab - ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I'm using ionic with angular 5 to create an app. Is there any way to launch an external website (via InAppBrowser for example) inside a tab? I mean, I would like to open an URL inside my app and still show the main menu (nav bar).

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: no... not so far!

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/)

Here is a [link](https://www.techiediaries.com/inappbrowser-ionic-v3/) to do it properly

Comment: It is not what i was looking for. Using InAppBrowser there is no way to open an URL and continue inside app and still show the main menu. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Ionic has native plugin to use afeature such as inAppBrowser.
What you probably have to do is just using some CSS

Comment: @AzoulayJason Can you please suggest how to set CSS here to get the requirement mentioned in this question ?